# Подключение к серверу по HTTPS (tlsv1/sslv3)

Tags: php, python, node.js, proxy, openssl

Требуется решение, которое позволяет клиентские запросы по https (tlsv1.2) переводить в https (tlsv1/ssl3) и отправлять их на конечный сервер. Сам конечный сервер обновлению не подлежит и требуется реализовать Work Around для поддержки старой системы.

Попытался реализовать решение на скриптах на nodejs, php, python, но столкнулся с тем, что библиотеки не работают с tlsv1.  Попробывал использовать mitmproxy, но и там проблема с поддержкой tlsv1.

Вопросы:
1) на каком языке программирования + версии + библиотеках можно реализовать требуемый функционал? Важно чтобы библиотека могла работать с tlsv1
2) Требуется ли даунгрейдить библиотеки openssl на операционных системах? 
3) Есть ли готовое opensource решение для данной задачи?

Comment: Может посмотреть в сторону HAproxy или Nginx?

Comment: Смотреть можно, НО нужно понимание какие версии использовать и требуется ли подстраивать OS? Если да, то как? какую os лучше использовать?  я сейчас думаю об centos 6.0

Answer (score 1):

Я бы для решения этой задачи воспользовался nginx reverse proxy.

1. Поднял бы легаси-сайт во внутренней сети, скажем https://legacy.intranet/
2. На новом фронтэнде установил бы nginx (версия Linux практически не имеет значения)
3. В файле /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/legacy.conf написал бы что-то вроде:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;


    ssl_certificate <path-certs>/example.com.cert.pem; # Сертификат для доменного имени
    ssl_certificate_key <path-certs>/example.com.key.pem; # Ключ для сертификата

    location / {
        # все запросы будут транслироваться один в один
        proxy_pass https://legacy.intranet;
        # Уменьшить накладные расходы на ssl handshake между прокси и легаси-сайтом
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        # Разрешить поддержку старых протоколов
        proxy_ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        # Мы доверяем собственному сайту, поэтому не будем проверять его сертификат
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }
}
```

Может возникнуть проблема с алгоритмами шифрования. Если сайт оооочень старый, то openssl на стороне прокси может не поддерживать алгоритмы, используемые в сервере. Например, в современных реализациях openssl по умолчанию нет реализации алгоритмов с дайджестом MD5. Тогда надо будет перекомпилировать openssl на стороне прокси, чтобы включить поддержку таких старых алгоритмов.

УПД.

Немного подумав, я понял, про что на самом деле вопрос.

Все современные дистрибутивы Linux идут с бинарником libssl, который не поддерживает SSLv3. Чтобы убедиться в этом, можно воспользоваться командой `s_client`, запретив все версии TLS - останется только SSLv3

`openssl s_client -no_tls1 -no_tls1_1 -no_tls1_2 -no_tls1_3 -connect google.com:443`

Результат:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
139791660487104:error:141E70BF:SSL routines:tls_construct_client_hello:no protocols available:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1125:
```

То есть реализация OpenSSL даже не может сформировать сообщение ClientHello по протоколу SSLv3.

Соответственно, даже если в конфигурационном файле nginx указать `proxy_ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3`, то nginx не сможет подключиться к серверу по SSLv3.

Идея решения.

1. Пересобирать общесистемную библиотеку libssl для поддержки SSLv3 - это нехорошо, ИМХО. Поэтому нужно скачать исходники openssl и собрать отдельный экземпляр бинарников с поддержкой SSLv3:

```
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl --openssldir=/opt/openssl enable-ssl3
make depend
make
sudo make install
```

Проверить: `/opt/openssl/bin/openssl s_client -no_tls1 -connect google.com:443`

Результат: `SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol:s23_clnt.c:735`

Гугл дал отлуп при попытке подключиться по SSLv3, но нам важно, что эта сборка OpenSSL таки смогла сформировать этот запрос.

2. Собрать отдельную версию nginx с кастомной сборкой libssl (не проверял!):

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/opt/openssl/ ...
```

На месте многоточия множество остальных параметров сборки. [Пример простыни](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-build-nginx-from-source-on-ubuntu-1804-lts/).

Для реверс прокси использовать именно эту версию `nginx`.

**!!НО!!**

Проще всего было бы поднять легаси сервер **БЕЗ HTTPS** на http://legacy.intranet/, а в конфигурационном файле nginx указать:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;

    ssl_certificate <path-certs>/example.com.cert.pem; # Сертификат для доменного имени
    ssl_certificate_key <path-certs>/example.com.key.pem; # Ключ для сертификата

    location / {
        # все запросы будут транслироваться один в один, только по HTTP
        proxy_pass http://legacy.intranet;
    }
}
```